# Scratch on aluminum trailer

Tags: trailer

Is there anyway that I can make this scratch look less visible? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Metal Buffing/polishing can help a great deal and ***maybe*** fix it.

If that doesn't resolve it to your satisfaction, you can use very fine grit sandpaper (800-3000); anything more aggressive will probably be noticeable and actually make things worse. Going to finer grits will make it more shiny as well, so you might need to stop at a coarser grit to match existing shine or go to a slightly finer grit if 3000 doesn't get it close.

1. Wipe it down with a clean cloth and sand with 800 grit
2. Wipe it down with a clean cloth and sand with 1500 grit
3. Wipe it down with a clean cloth and sand with 3000 grit
4. Polish with aluminum polish
5. Buff with a clean cloth

Comment: The only thing I can say about your method is, I think the aluminum is brushed, not polished. If you go through and polish it, you'll have "bright" spots in the aluminum which won't match the rest of the aluminum.

Comment: Personally, I think any DIY attempt to re-brush brushed aluminium will just leave a patch the size of the attempted fix that you'll be able to see from 80 yards.

Comment: So the answer is...paint it?

Answer (score 1):

[Turtle Wax 53836 Hybrid Solutions Scratch Repair Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BL42V9VY)

[3-pk Squeegee](https://drcolorchip.com/product/3-pk-squeegee/)

Using a squeegee, apply only the Clear-Coat Fill & Seal (from the Turtle Wax Kit) to the scratches.  While it is still wet, remove any excess clear coat filler using a cloth dipped in acetone.  Allow to dry and apply a second coat, if necessary, so that you cannot feel any scratches with your fingernail.  If the end result is a bit too shinny, rub the scratches gently with a pencil eraser or #0000 steel wool.

Throughout the process, be precise enough to treat only the scratch.  Avoid the idea that you will overlap the scratch with filler/rubbing and somehow "blend" into the surrounding area.  In my experience, that method usually leads to an amateur result at best and a nasty mess at worst.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is cover it up with a decal.  It will be visible through paint.  I hope you got insurance money because that looks to be a couple grand in damage.